# Pandas Grouping by Hostname. Average of Sessions(on host) by Hour

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, average

The dataframe looks like this.

```
              datetime   hostname  sessions
0  2020-10-27 00:00:05  server001        22
1  2020-10-27 00:00:10  server001        25
2  2020-10-27 00:00:15  server001        21
3  2020-10-27 01:00:05  server001        30
4  2020-10-27 01:00:10  server001        30
5  2020-10-27 01:00:15  server001        35
6  2020-10-27 00:00:05  server002        15
7  2020-10-27 00:00:10  server002        10
8  2020-10-27 00:00:15  server002        11
9  2020-10-27 01:00:05  server002        19
10 2020-10-27 01:00:10  server002        22
11 2020-10-27 01:00:15  server002        18
```

What I am trying to show the average sessions per hour by individual hostname.

So I would get something back like this.

```
              datetime   hostname  sessions
0  2020-10-27 00:00:00  server001        23
1  2020-10-27 01:00:00  server001        32
2  2020-10-27 00:00:00  server002        12
3  2020-10-27 01:00:00  server002        20
```

I think I'm getting my grouping wrong as when trying this what I end up with is typically the largest average value per hour for any given hostname ordered in date by hour.

For example I may see something like

```
                hostname   datetime     sessions
0  2020-10-27  server001   00:00:00           23
1  2020-10-27              01:00:00           32
2  2020-10-27  server002   02:00:00           12
3  2020-10-27  server003   03:00:00           20
```

Rather than the full 24 hours per hostname listed.

The code I tried was:

```
df = df.groupby(['hostname']).resample(
        'H', on='datetime'
        ).agg({'sessions': 'mean'}).round(0).astype(int)
```

What do I need to do to get the desired result?

Comment: why don't you extract hour from the date time column and create a coumn along with date column(not datetime) and then group by "date column","hour","hostname"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example based on the data you have provided. I have added the steps to make dates into datetime (in case they were objects) and to set datetime as a `datetimeindex` in order to use `resample`. It would go something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d ={'datetime' :['2020-10-27 00:00:05','2020-10-27 00:00:10','2020-10-27 00:00:15','2020-10-27 01:00:05','2020-10-27 01:00:10','2020-10-27 01:00:15','2020-10-27 00:00:05','2020-10-27 00:00:10','2020-10-27 00:00:15','2020-10-27 01:00:05','2020-10-27 01:00:10','2020-10-27 01:00:15'],
   'hostname':['server001','server001','server001','server001','server001','server001','server002','server002','server002','server002','server002','server002'],
   'sessions':[ 22,25,21 ,30,30,35,15,10, 11,19,22,18]}       
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime']))
df.resample('H').mean()
```

Actually, you can modify this example to fit other purposes. As I understood your question, you want to calculate hourly mean number of sessions. Check the `resample`-function if you need other groupby.s

The alternative to doing this is to seaprate `date` and `time` and then take the mean:

```
df['datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['Date'] = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in df['datetime'].tolist()]
df['Time'] = ['%s:00' % x.strftime('%H') for x in df['datetime'].tolist()]
df_1 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Time', 'hostname']).mean()
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that only does the mean value for the entire span of sessions.

What I need is this grouped up by hostnames and then their individual mean average of sessions.

Comment: Reading this again it looks like it may give the solution. For some reason I did not see the last bit I think there was a problem on the device I was viewing it on. This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Please see second example by **Serge de Gosson de Varnnes** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64646652/2986801). This does **exactly** what I was looking for.

I believe I have found a solution to my answer. The first mistake I was making was not creating an index by the hour. I believe **Amit Kumar** was talking about this, but I could not quite grasp at the time what he meant. And **Serge de Gosson de Varnnes** also had set an index on the data in the his example as well.

I'll use **Serge de Gosson de Varnnes's** example of my data insertion so anyone that finds this can take the immediate example and check the output:

```
import pandas as pd

d ={'datetime' :['2020-10-27 00:00:05','2020-10-27 00:00:10','2020-10-27 00:00:15','2020-10-27 01:00:05','2020-10-27 01:00:10','2020-10-27 01:00:15','2020-10-27 00:00:05','2020-10-27 00:00:10','2020-10-27 00:00:15','2020-10-27 01:00:05','2020-10-27 01:00:10','2020-10-27 01:00:15'],
   'hostname':['server001','server001','server001','server001','server001','server001','server002','server002','server002','server002','server002','server002'],
   'sessions':[ 22,25,21 ,30,30,35,15,10, 11,19,22,18]}       
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime']))

hour_index = df.index.hour

df = groupby([hour_index, 'hostname'])['sessions'].mean().round(0).astype(int)

with pd.option_context(
        'display.max_rows',
         None,
         'display.max_columns',
         None
         ):
    print(df)
```

The round and astype methods are applied here to round up to the nearest integer. This wasn't something I specified before as I already knew how to handle this, but I'll put it here for completeness.

The with statement here is to allow the printing of the full dataframe (be careful with large dataframes as this can be a lot of data to print on screen at once).

Output:

```
datetime  hostname 
0         server001    23
          server002    12
1         server001    32
          server002    20
```

The only improvement here that would be nice would be the index by hour to be in a clock format with a timestamp.

Another thing this doesn't address, but was outside of the scope of this particular question is if there are multiple days within the datetime column. I will be separating my dataframes in a per day per dataframe to deal with this. But should I find a better way of dealing with each day I'll add this to my solution.